# JS Regex multiple capturing groups return all matches

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to create a regex to extract data from the string. My sample string: `dn1:pts-sc1.1`. Format of a data I expect: `['pts', 'sc', '1.1']` so basically every set of letters after `:` and the numbers from the end.

What i [have right now](https://regex101.com/r/7ZPwz2/2):

`/^[^:]+:(?:([a-z]+)-?)+([\d\.]+)$/g`

Unfortunately, it returns only last set of letters.
`['sc', '1.1']`

I also tried to add `+` to the first capturing group:

`/^[^:]+:(?:([a-z]+)+-?)+([\d\.]+)$/g`

The result in the same. Only difference in that regex101 gives me this comment:

> A repeated capturing group will only capture the last iteration. Put a capturing group around the repeated group to capture all iterations or use a non-capturing group instead if you're not interested in the data

--edit

examples of input string:

- `dn2.33:sc-pts-tt-as3.43`
- `dn2.33:sc3.43`
- `dn2.33:sc-tt-as3.43`

So basically I don't know the number of letter groups.

Comment: You may not get arbitrary number of groups, their number is specified by the number of capturing groups in your pattern. Why not use [`/^[^:]+:([a-z]+)-([a-z]+)([\d.]+)$/`](https://regex101.com/r/xhUe8z/1)?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I added some additional info in the edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may not get arbitrary number of groups, their number is specified by the number of capturing groups in your pattern. You may instead match and capture the `-`-separated values into 1 group and then split it with `-` to get individual items and build the result dynamically:

```js
var strs = ['dn2.33:sc-pts-tt-as3.43','dn2.33:sc3.43','dn2.33:sc-tt-as3.43'];
var rx = /^[^:]+:([a-z]+(?:-[a-z]+)*)([\d.]+)$/; // Define the regex
for (var s of strs) {
  var res = [];             // The resulting array variable
  var m = rx.exec(s);       // Run the regex search
  if (m) {                  // If there is a match...
    res = m[1].split('-');  // Split Group 1 value with - and assign to res
    res.push(m[2]);         // Add Group 2 value to the resulting array
  }
  console.log(s, "=>", res);
}
```

The pattern - `^[^:]+:([a-z]+(?:-[a-z]+)*)([\d.]+)$` - will match the following:

- `^` - start of string
- `[^:]+` - 1+ chars other than `:`
- `:` - a colon
- `([a-z]+(?:-[a-z]+)*)` - Group 1 (it will be `abc-def-ghij`...): 1 or more letters followed with 0+ consecutive sequences of `-` and 1+ letters (add `/i` modifier to make the pattern case insensitive)
- `([\d.]+)` - Group 2 (it can be just "push"ed into to the resulting array as `m[2]`): 1 or more digits or `.`
- `$` - end of string.